# Ungrouping effect?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dynamic set of data *X* of the form:

```
----------------------------------
x.id | x.allocated | x.unallocated
----------------------------------
foo  | 2           | 0
bar  | 1           | 2
----------------------------------
```

And I need to get to a result of *Y* (order is unimportant):

```
----------------------------------
y.id | y.state
----------------------------------
foo  | allocated
foo  | allocated
bar  | allocated
bar  | unallocated
bar  | unallocated
----------------------------------
```

I have a UTF based solution, but I'm looking for hyper-efficiency so I'm idly wondering if there's a statement based, non-procedural way to get this kind of "ungroup by" effect?

It feels like an unpivot, but my brain can't get there right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Sql Server 2005, [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), and [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) you can try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        id VARCHAR(20),
        allocated INT,
        unallocated INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'foo', 2, 0
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'bar', 1, 2

;WITH vals AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    
        (
            SELECT  id,
                    allocated,
                    unallocated
            FROM    @Table
        ) p
        UNPIVOT (Cnt FOR Action IN (allocated, unallocated)) unpvt
        WHERE   Cnt > 0
)
, Recurs AS (
        SELECT  id,
                Action,
                Cnt - 1 Cnt
        FROM    vals
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id,
                Action,
                Cnt - 1 Cnt
        FROM    Recurs
        WHERE   Cnt > 0

)
SELECT  id,
        Action
FROM    Recurs
ORDER BY id, action
```

Comment: I knew it was unpivotable :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a numbers table in your database, you could use that to help get your results.  In my database, I have a table named Numbers with a Num column.

```
Declare @Temp Table(id VarChar(10), Allocated Int, UnAllocated Int)

Insert Into @Temp Values('foo', 2, 0)
Insert Into @Temp Values('bar',1, 2)

Select T.id,'Allocated' 
From   @Temp T 
       Inner Join Numbers 
          On T.Allocated >= Numbers.Num
Union All
Select T.id,'Unallocated' 
From   @Temp T 
       Inner Join Numbers 
          On T.unAllocated >= Numbers.Num
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, but obviously breaks down at extreme number ranges unless you want to generate bigint.max rows in your table. Almost certainly the most efficient solution, but I dislike polluting my DB with support mechanisms.

Comment: Polluting a DB with support mechanisms?  Really?  I think that's the definition of an index.  Indexes exists to support your DB's querying performance.  I bet you have a bunch of those in your database.

Comment: @annakata - You're a real joker! Do you realize that the numbers in the OP's question are actually being translated into real rows in a real result set? Whatever the rowcount is going to be of the final result set, if the server and application can handle that, they can handle a numbers table to go along with it. Allowing for some unlikely colossal system, one table with 2^31-1 integer values in it is only about 8 Gb of data. Returning 2,147,483,647 rows is thus no problem, and I guarantee this solution will outperform your CTE by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Emtucifor - Well you obviously didn't realise that *I am the OP*. I deeply object to creating independent structures in a domain which do not map to domain objects. This is the logical equivalent of static methods and helper classes imho, and I don't think the index comparison is relevant because indexes are not independant of their tables.

Comment: @annakata - You're right. I missed that fact. Haha on me! You are of course entitled to your opinion. I just had to say my piece about why I thought it wasn't a well-founded one. In my perspective, satisfying theoretical idealism at the expense of simplicity and performance is, well, a mistake. I think of a numbers table as making up for a missing feature that ought to be in SQL Server: a function that returns a rowset of numbers within a certain range. This should be so easy for the engine to build and could be all in memory. In the meantime, it's a GREAT way for solving problems.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, why can't a numbers table be a domain object? It is the list of quantities that are possible to be allocated or unallocated. While it seems funny because it's just a list of numbers, it's a perfectly valid extension of the business information space.

Comment: @annakata - in thinking about this later, I realized I was unnecessarily rude to you. Sorry about that. I could have expressed myself less condescendingly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to ping back to G Mastros and doesn't need any upvotes. I thought he would appreciate a performance boost to his already superior query.

```
SELECT
   T.id,
   CASE X.Which WHEN 1 THEN 'Allocated' ELSE 'Unallocated' END
FROM
   @Temp T 
   INNER JOIN Numbers N
      On N.Num <= CASE X.Which WHEN 1 THEN T.Allocated ELSE T.Unallocated END
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) X (Which)
```

Comment: Is `Numbers` a system table/view? Is it available in `SQL Server 2005`?

Comment: It's just a table with the numbers 1 to 100,000 or some high amount.