# MySQL Query to Ungroup Data

Tags: mysql

I have the same exact question as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469328/ungrouping-effect), but for MySQL rather than SQL Server.  Can ungrouping be done with MySQL?  MySQL doesn't have an "Unpivot" function unfortunately.  Here is an example of what I need:

Raw Data:

```
----------------------------------
owner id |   name    | occurances
----------------------------------
1        |   red     | 4
1        |   yellow  | 2
1        |   green   | 3
----------------------------------
```

Query to output:

```
---------------
id |   name
---------------
1  |   red
1  |   red
1  |   red
1  |   red
1  |   yellow
1  |   yellow
1  |   green
1  |   green
1  |   green
---------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a set of numbers for this.  Here is one way:

```
 select id, name
 from t join
       (select d1.d + 10 * d2.d + 100*d3.d as num
        from (select 1 as d union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
              select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
              select 7 union all select 8 unin all select 9 union all select 0
             ) d1 cross join
              (select 1 as d union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
              select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
              select 7 union all select 8 unin all select 9 union all select 0
             ) d2 cross join
              (select 1 as d union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
              select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
              select 7 union all select 8 unin all select 9 union all select 0
             ) d3
        ) n
        where n.num between 1 and occurrences
```

This works for numbers up to 999.